# What is the metric for distance_upper_bound parameter in scipy.spatial.KDTree.query?

Tags: python, data-structures, scipy

I am new to using scipy. I can't quite seem to figure out the metric of `distance_upper_bound` in `scipy.spatial.KDTree.query`. Is it in **Kilometers** or **Radians**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the value in terms of the chosen metric on which you decided using parameter `p`.

If you did chose `p=1`, aka manhattan-distance, the distance of the vectors: `x=[1,2,3]` and `y=[2,3,4]` is `3`. If you would have used `distance_upper_bound=2` and `y` is the next neighbor to `x` you are looking for, don't expect a correct result.

Remark: this parameter you are talking about is set to `inf` by default.

**Your task** seems to be about latitude/longitude points. In this case, i think you want to use the [Haversine-metric](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (disclaimer: i'm no expert in this area).

Sadly, this metric is imho not available in terms of a [p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions), the only ones supported in scipy's neighbor-searches!

But: sklearn's [BallTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#ball-tree) can work with Haversine! (KDTree does not! Still p-norms!)

There is probably a good reason (either math or practical performance) why KDTree is not supporting Haversine, while BallTree does. Don't try to roll your own Haversine-KDTree blindly!

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549402/kdtree-for-longitude-latitude):

> A binary search tree cannot handle the wraparound of the polar representation by design. You might need to transform the coordinates to a 3D cartesian space and then apply your favorite search algorithm, e.g., kD-Tree, Octree etc.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree, BallTree

KDTree.valid_metrics
# ['euclidean', 'l2', 'minkowski', 'p', 'manhattan', 'cityblock', 'l1', 'chebyshev',
#  'infinity']

BallTree.valid_metrics
# ['euclidean', 'l2', 'minkowski', 'p', 'manhattan', 'cityblock', 'l1', 'chebyshev',
#  'infinity', 'seuclidean', 'mahalanobis', 'wminkowski', 'hamming', 'canberra',
#  'braycurtis', 'matching', 'jaccard', 'dice', 'kulsinski', 'rogerstanimoto', 'russellrao',
#  'sokalmichener', 'sokalsneath', 'haversine', 'pyfunc']
```

Comment: Let's say I have latitudes and longitudes as input. What should be the value of p then? Also, I thought the method will return all the nearest neighbors which is <= distance_upper_bound. Isn't that the case?

Comment: That's a question not much suited here i suppose as more math-based. I'm not sure what people do in this research-area. But yes: given some metric, you can ask for all neighbors with less distance in regards to this metric. Important: *metric*! MAybe **haversine**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that saved me some troubles. I will implement my own Kd Tree.

Comment: Sure. I read it. It's better to implement my own, as it would help in the adhoc parameter controls.

Comment: Why? What controls? sklearn's NeighborSearches are preeeetty good.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: And think about the alternative mentioned in my link. But i can't help with this. You may have more knowledge there (mapping).