# KNN algorithm that return 2 or more nearest neighbours

Tags: scikit-learn

For example, I have a vector `x` and `a` is it's nearest neigbour. Then, `b` is it's next nearest neighbour. Is there any package in Pyton or R that outputs something like `[a, b]` meaning that a is its nearest neighbour(maybe by majority vote), while b is it's second nearest neighbour.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what those metric-trees are build for.

Your question reads as you are asking for something as simple as that using sklearn's [KDTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree) (consider BallTree depending on your metric in play):

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

X = np.array([[1,1],[2,2], [3,3]])  # 3 points in 2 dimensions
tree = KDTree(X)
dist, ind = tree.query([[1.25, 1.35]], k=2)
print(ind)  # indices of 2 closest neighbors
print(dist)  # distances to 2 closest neighbors
```

Out:

```
[[0 1]]
[[ 0.43011626  0.99247166]]
```

And just to be clear: KNN *usually* refers to some pre-build algorithm based on metric-trees (KDTree, BallTree) for the task of classification. Often those data-structures are the only thing one is interested in.

**Edit**

If i interpret your comment correctly, you want to use the [manhattan / taxicab / l1 metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46934629/2320035) for the compatibility lists of those spatial-trees.

You just would use it like that:

```python
X = np.array([[1,1],[2,2], [3,3]])  # 3 points in 2 dimensions
tree = KDTree(X, metric='l1')                                         # !!!
dist, ind = tree.query([[1.25, 1.35]], k=2)
print(ind)  # indices of 2 closest neighbors
print(dist)  # distances to 2 closest neighbors
```

Out:

```
[[0 1]]
[[ 0.6  1.4]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you pleas help me with inserting my own distance metric, which is distance matrix of elements of vectors? for example if I have two vectors [x1, x2] and [y2, y2] is it possible to insert distance metric that gets distance between vectors on element-by-element basis from distance matrix. So distance between x and y is |x1-y1|+|x2-y2|.

Comment: If I try `tree = KDTree(X, metric=dist)``with distbeing function dist(x, y) that returns float I get error:ValueError: metric PyFuncDistance is not valid for KDTree

Comment: Thanks for help, but I want my own metric. Similarity of my vector is custom. Numbers are only codes for some characterstics, and characteristics 1 and 2 have distance 9, while 1 and 3 have 1....just an example. All this is saved in a matrix and this matrix will be updated and charateristics have to stay numbered as they are. I have also asked this already(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981662/distance-matrix-with-knn) but no response so any tip is more than welcome :)

Comment: @spartan That's because this other question is way too informal. You should edit it. Less text, more math, more formatting.

Comment: @sacha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042408/kd-tree-with-custom-distance-metric - I hope this question is correct now