# Speed up getting distance between two lat and lon

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, gis, geopy

I have two DataFrame containing Lat and Lon. I want to find distance from one `(Lat, Lon)` pair to **ALL** `(Lat, Lon)` from another DataFrame and get the minimum. The package that I am using `geopy`. The code is as follows:

```
from geopy import distance
import numpy as np

distanceMiles = []
count = 0
for id1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    target = (row1["LAT"], row1["LON"])
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    for id2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        point = (row2["LAT"], row2["LON"])
        distanceMiles.append(distance.distance(target, point).miles)

    closestPoint = np.argmin(distanceMiles)
    distanceMiles = []
```

The problem is that `df1` has `168K` rows and `df2` has `1200` rows. How do I make it faster?

Answer (score 6):

`geopy.distance.distance` [uses `geodesic` algorithm by default](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.20.0/#module-geopy.distance), which is rather slow but more accurate. If you can trade accuracy for speed, you can use `great_circle`, which is ~20 times faster:

```
In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: distance.distance(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles
   ...:
236 µs ± 1.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: distance.great_circle(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles
   ...:
13.4 µs ± 94.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Also you may use multiprocessing to parallelize the computation:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from geopy import distance
import numpy as np


def compute(points):
    target, point = points
    return distance.great_circle(target, point).miles


with Pool() as pool:
    for id1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
        target = (row1["LAT"], row1["LON"])
        distanceMiles = pool.map(
            compute,
            (
                (target, (row2["LAT"], row2["LON"]))
                for id2, row2 in df2.iterrows()
            )
        )
        closestPoint = np.argmin(distanceMiles)
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here in case anyone needs it in the future:

If you need only the minimum distance, then you don't have to bruteforce all the pairs. There are some data structures that can help you solve this in O(n*log(n)) time complexity, which is way faster than the bruteforce method.

For example, you can use a generalized KNearestNeighbors (with k=1) algorithm to do exactly that, given that you pay attention to your points being on a sphere, not a plane. See [this SO answer for an example implementation using sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56619995/9094710).

There seems to be a few libraries to solve this too, like [sknni](https://pypi.org/project/sknni/) and [GriSPy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2213133720300974?dgcid=rss_sd_all).

[Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48128/find-k-nearest-neighbors-on-a-sphere)'s also another question that talks a bit about the theory.

Answer (score 0):

This should run much faster if you utilize itertools instead of explicit for loops. Inline comments should help you understand whats happening at each step.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from geopy import distance


#Creating 2 sample dataframes with 10 and 5 rows of lat, long columns respectively
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'LAT':np.random.random(10,), 'LON':np.random.random(10,)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'LAT':np.random.random(5,), 'LON':np.random.random(5,)})


#Zip the 2 columns to get (lat, lon) tuples for target in df1 and point in df2
target = list(zip(df1['LAT'], df1['LON']))
point = list(zip(df2['LAT'], df2['LON']))


#Product function in itertools does a cross product between the 2 iteratables
#You should get things of the form ( ( lat, lon), (lat, lon) ) where 1st is target, second is point. Feel free to change the order if needed
product = list(itertools.product(target, point)])

#starmap(function, parameters) maps the distance function to the list of tuples. Later you can use i.miles for conversion
geo_dist = [i.miles for i in itertools.starmap(distance.distance, product)]
len(geo_dist)
```

```
50
```

```
geo_dist = [42.430772028845716,
 44.29982320107605,
 25.88823239877388,
 23.877570442142783,
 29.9351451072828,
 ...]
```

Finally, 
If you are working with a massive dataset, then I would recommend using multiprocessing library to map the itertools.starmap to different cores and asynchronously compute the distance values. Python Multiprocessing library now supports starmap.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check **all** the the pairs by brute force, I think the following approach is the best you can do.
Looping directly on columns is usually slightly faster than `iterrows`, and the vectorized approach replacing the inner loop saves time too.

```
for lat1, lon1 in zip(df1["LAT"], df1["LON"]):
    target = (lat1, lon1)
    count = count + 1
    #    print(count) #printing is also time expensive
    df2['dist'] = df1.apply(lambda row : distance.distance(target, (row['LAT'], row['LON'])).miles, axis=1)
    closestpoint = df2['dist'].min() #if you want the minimum distance
    closestpoint = df2['dist'].idxmin() #if you want the position (index) of the minimum.
```