# Unsure how to further optimise (get rid of for loop)

Tags: pandas, for-loop, optimization, geopy

I am working on several datasets. One dataset (geodata - 74 observations) contains Indian district names, latitude and longitude of district centres while the other (called rainfall_2009) contains information on rainfall in a geographic grid as well as grid's latitude and longitude. The aim is to link each grid to a district such that the grid's distance from the district centre would be no more than 100 km. The dataset is big - 350 000 observations. I initially tried running 2 loops, but I know this is a very unPythonic way and in the end it was very inefficient, taking around 2.5h. I have managed to get rid of one of the loops, but it still takes 1.5h to run the code. Is there any further way I could optimise it?

```
# Create empty variables for district names and distance to the centre

rainfall_2009['district'] = np.nan
rainfall_2009['distance'] = np.nan

# Make a tuple of district centre geographic location (to be used in distance geodesic command)

geodata['location'] = pd.Series([tuple(i) for i in np.array((np.array(geodata.centroid_latitude) , np.array(geodata.centroid_longitude))).T])

# Run the loop for each grid in the dataset. 

for i in tqdm(rainfall_2009.index):
    place = (rainfall_2009.latitude.iloc[i], rainfall_2009.longitude.iloc[i]) # select grid's geographic data
    distance = geodata.location.apply(lambda x: dist.geodesic(place, x).km) # construct series of distances between grid and all regional centers
    if list(distance[distance<100]) == []: # If there are no sufficiently close district centers we just continue the loop
        continue
    else:
        # We take the minimum distance to assign the closest region. 
        rainfall_2009.district.iloc[i] = geodata.distname_iaa.iloc[distance[distance < 100].idxmin()]
        rainfall_2009.distance.iloc[i] = distance[distance < 100].min()
```

Comment: If you can trade accuracy for speed then you can use `great_circle` instead of `geodesic`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57189777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pass pandas columns directly to `dist.geodesic()`?  Calling this via the apply() statement may be slow.

This example might be helpful (see the function `gcd_vec()` in this blog post:
https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance

Also, can you perform *fewer* distance calculations?  For example calculate distance from geographic grid to district center if the two end-points are in the same state or adjacent states?

UPDATE:
The Numba package may speed this up further.  You just import and apply a decorator.  Details here:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def gcd_vec():
    # same as before
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was stuck because dist.geodesic() only accepts point as entries (hence why I used apply) but this one takes arrays too which brought it down to 10 minutes! 

[Sadly I can't perform fewer distance calculations since I have no idea which state grids are located]