# Calculating coordinate distances with geopy in a pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, coordinates, geopy

> I have the code below that works for calculating distances between
> coordinates of cities where a trip with public transport is started
> and the coordinates of cities where the trip is ended and returns the
> value. There is a unique number of combinations from a particular city
> and to a particular city, The problem is that I have a large data set
> of around 1.2 million records and the code is rather slow because it
> iterates for each combination. How can I rearrange the loop so it
> calculates the distances between coordinates for the unique
> combinations and applies it to combinations that are repeated? Is
> there any way that takes less processing times?

```
df_distance = []
for row in clean_df.iterrows():
    try:
        coords_1 = (row[1].Lat_x, row[1].Lng_x)
        coords_2 = (row[1].Lat_y, row[1].Lng_y)
        distance = geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km
        df_distance.append(distance)
        #print(geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(row)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57189777

Answer (score 0):

> I rewrote the loop which shortens the processing time of my dataset
> coordinates distance calculations:
> I created an empty dictionary that will save the distance calculations for unique combinations of origin-destination trips. For unique combinations create a unique code that will sum as a string the codes of the origin and destination municipalities and add them to the dictionary. If such a unique code is encounter again (repeated) add the distance to the dictionary else calculate the distance and add it to the dictionary.

```
distance_dict = {}
df_distance = list()
for row in clean_df.iterrows():
    try:
        uniquecode = str(row[1].from_municipality_code) + str(row[1].to_municipality_code)
        if uniquecode in distance_dict:
            df_distance.append(distance_dict[uniquecode])
            continue
        else:
            coords_1 = (row[1].Lat_x, row[1].Lng_x)
            coords_2 = (row[1].Lat_y, row[1].Lng_y)
            distance = geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km
            distance_dict[uniquecode] = distance
            df_distance.append(distance)
        #print(geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(row)
```